# Android View is not respecting parent layout padding

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

So I'm doing a little project where I need a autocomplete box for inputting some wares a for a shopping list. I am having some troubles though as the dropdown box is not respecting the bottom margins of the linear layout. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutShoppingList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropDownAnchor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.printz.guano.shoppingassistant.DefaultTopAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteAddWare"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:dropDownAnchor="@id/dropDownAnchor"
            android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/add_ware_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/editTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCloseDropDown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_ware_description"
            android:text="Close"
            android:textColor="@color/colorToolbarSecondayText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewWares"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: The autocomplete view]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you can solve this problem by inserting `android:paddingBottom="?dp"` inside the `LinearLayout` or inserting `android:marginBottom="?dp"` inside the `ListView`.

Replace `?` with a number

Comment: This made no difference. I tried adding bottom padding to the listview and nothing changed, the linear layout already has a padding